# Return data from node js to $.ajax

Tags: node.js

From one of the machines in my network (client), I am making `$.ajax()` request to my `Nodejs` server like,

`//Client : index.html`

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:'http://192.168.2.6:8080',
    data:JSON.stringify({"loginData":{"uanme":"maverick","upass":"asd"}}),
    success:function(data){console.log(data);alert(data);},
    error:function(){alert('Error aala');}
});
```

AND my `Nodejs` server is

`//listener.js`

```
var server = require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
    var body='';
    if(request.method=='POST'){
       request.on('data',function(data){
            body+=data;
       });
       request.on('end',function(){
           console.log(body);
       });
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

These `console.log()`s are working absolutely fine. I get the exact same data I am sending on the node side,

Now my question is, in `php` when we make an `$.ajax()` request, we use `echo` in our php file to send the data back to the client,

What should I have to do on server side in `Nodejs (listener.js file)` if I want to send the data back to the client?

Comment: `response` http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem myself.

The problem was with cross domain ajax requests.
I don't know why this was happening, even though I had specified `url:localhost:8080` in my `$.ajax` call...

Solved the problem my adding 
`response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`
in my response headers.

PEACE

Comment: It is across origins because the HTML file is served from default HTTP with `:80` and you are POSTing to `:8080` which is totally different. To avoid this you would need to set up a single proxy to hit, or serve your HTML through Node.

Answer (score 1):

```
var server = require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
    var body='';
    if(request.method=='POST'){
       request.on('data',function(data){
            body+=data;
       });
       request.on('end',function(){
           console.log(body);
           //response.setHeader("Content-Type", ""); set the header to your content type
           response.write('foo'); // <-----
           response.end('Dear client, I have cake for you'); // <-----
       });
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

Further reading [Node.js Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html)

Comment: Tried... Didn't work.. :( My `error` handler in `$.ajax` on `client side` is getting called... When does this `success` handler get called?

Comment: As I just realized: You specify an IP address in your code. I guess you are getting some sort of cross domain error.

Comment: still no luck..
And about the cross domain thing, Now I am running both things on the same machine...
Let me try starting google chrome with `--disable-web-security` option...

Comment: and that didn't work even after replacing that hard coded `IP address` with `localhost`.